# Help with subgroup contain

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ a group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$ and define $N=\bigcap_{x\in G}{xHx^{-1}}$, show that for all $a\in G$ $N\subseteq aNa^{-1}$.

Any hint or advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* It is enough to prove that $a^{-1}Na \subseteq N$ for all $a\in G$.

Solution:

> $N \subseteq xHx^{-1}$ for all $x \in G$. Therefore, $a^{-1}Na \subseteq a^{-1}xHx^{-1}a=y H y^{-1}$ for $y=a^{-1}x$. As $x$ runs through $G$, so does $y=a^{-1}x$. Therefore, $a^{-1}Na  \subseteq \bigcap_{y\in G}{yHy^{-1}} = N$.